# Does Cheibriados' Slouch affect Oklob plants?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

As stationary monsters I wouldn't expect it to, but the wiki says they have a move speed of 10 (even if they don't ever use it). Whether it can or can't will determine whether I'm able to take on this oklob yet, or whether I need to come back later with better ranged options or controlled blink. I'm a warper, and have already seen an Akashic record in a shop, so I WILL have controlled blink eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, Slouch does not affect stationary monsters, no matter their speed stat.